# Why is Umbraco Load Package button always disabled for Install local package?

Tags: package, umbraco

I am trying to install a package in Umbraco 7.1.8 using the Install local package page. I click the checkmark that I understand the security risks, browse to the zip file and then try to click the Load Package button. The button just shows a red circle with a line through it and isn't clickable. I've tried changed the order of clicking the checkbox and browsing but no luck. I've attached a screenshot of the page although the cursor isn't captured in the screenshot.

This happens locally and on my Azure server. Inspecting the button shows it is disabled.

Any suggestions would be appreciated,

Jason

[image]

Comment: Is this an issue when trying to install other packages, or this specific package?

Comment: @PTuckley - I've tried a few different ones with no luck.